# realtime joystick end effector control

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, joystick, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i use joystick to move robotic arm in rviz
then i press "plan" and "execute", then real arm moving.

how can i make that action without "plan" and "execute".
i am trying to make: when the virtual arm moves, the real arm moves at the same time.
real time joystick control

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372716/realtime-joystick-end-effector-control/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Canonical answer these days is almost always -- if looking for something MoveIt based/related: [MoveIt Servo](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html).

Alternatively, if you want to work with something even more low-level: [fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/cartesian_controllers](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/cartesian_controllers).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-02-25**:
you are my hero

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-25**:
Thank the guys who wrote it.